# Using averageifs function for time point

Tags: excel, if-statement, time, average

I'm stuck with an AVERAGEIFS function in excel and I'm hoping to get some input here. I'm working with data on sleep and have multiple entries per person. I want to know what the average midsleep (the time you go to bed + sleep duration/2) on free days is for one person in week 1 and week 2. So basically just a time point in hh:mm. I already have calculated midsleep for each data point.

What I already did and has worked for sleep duration, e.g. =AVERAGEIFS(BZ2:BZ266, B2:B266, "8469", CC2:CC266, "1", CG2:CG266, "1") the average sleep duration for person 8469 in week 1 on work days (1).

For midsleep it also has worked, but not always. I think there must be going on something with how time works in excel. For example I get 17:49 as person 8470's
average midsleep in week 2, but the average sum is 11:39. If I then divide 11:39 into two, it's 17:49 again.

I used the same formula here: =AVERAGEIFS(CB2:CB266,C2:C266,"8470",CG2:CG266,"2",CH2:CH266,"2") - the midlsleep point in week 2 on free days (2).

Do you have any idea what's happening here? It seems to be a time issue. My columns are formatted as hh:mm.

Let me know if you need more information.

All the best,
Anita

Comment: Is the data a time series  e.g. right now is 43,216.66 on my computer

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I think the issue was that some of the time points (hh:mm) also had a date next to them which I had only seen when I clicked at them. I think it's working now :)

Comment: Excellent. Glad it's working

Comment: @CFO you may share the answer in the Answer tab, to remove this question from 'unanswered' list. & Anita can accept it like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). | Alternatively, the question owner (Anita) may do so too..  ( :

Comment: [····](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295912/which-option-shall-i-use-to-close-questions-with-answers-in-comments)